# How to detect page opened from click, iframe or image PHP?

Tags: php, image, iframe, click

Link:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://mysite.com/traffic_analityc.php">My Link</a>
```

or image:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/traffic_analityc.php" />
```

or iframe :

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/traffic_analityc.php"></iframe>
```

Thank's before..!

Comment: @qwertymk . can you point me in the right direction?..Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Add a `GET` reference in each link and then get that reference in `traffic_analityc.php`:

*LINK*:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://mysite.com/traffic_analityc.php?src=href">My Link</a>
```

*IMAGE*:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/traffic_analityc.php?src=img" />
```

*IFRAME*:

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/traffic_analityc.php?src=iframe"></iframe>
```

And then in the `traffic_analityc.php`:

```
$source = isset($_GET['src']) ? $_GET['src'] : '';
```

`$source` will of course equal either href, img or iframe.

Comment: Trinity operators are bad. Even more, if you write : instead of ? ;)

Comment: @cem For the purposes of this answer it will suffice. That was a mistake, thanks for letting me know lol.

Comment: I was about to correct it on my own, but a single char edit is not allowed :(

Comment: @F4r-20 , Thank's. But the code on other site that we don't have access to edit html code